# Building a dll for multiple targets (Silverlight, .Net3.5 etc) - are there any standard naming conventions

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, build

I have a .Net project, which has one build artefact - a dll. I'd like to create a build script that can multi-target frameworks, in other words provide a dll for .Net3.5, one for Silverlight etc.

Is there a standard naming convention/structure for the output directory? I've seen things like 'net35' in nuget packages, but I don't know if that scheme is arbitrary or not. Is there an Microsoft standard 'short form' for the various target frameworks?

I'd still like to also have mutiple build configs per target - for example Debug and Release.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the [Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx).  This would allow you to write a single assembly usable from multiple targets, instead of trying to build multiple versions.

Comment: Interesting. Although my project has few dependencies, so would otherwise be a good candidate, I'm targeting .Net Micro framework and .net 3.5 so I'm not sure that would work.